# Is there a way to automatically persist the parent id to the child entity on a @ManyToOne relationship in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have a Department and Employee entities in my application and I want to be able to save a Department but in the save action also save any employees that might be provided.

I am using Cascade.PERSIST, the Department and Employee entities are saved but the problem is that the department_id (the foreign key) is not automatically saved in the employee entities.

I know that I could set the department to each employee to the service layer but I was wondering if there is any other way (maybe some annotation or attribute) so that the department id is saved automatically.

Sample Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENTS")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String deptName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Set<Employee> employees;
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private Double salary;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Department department;
    // getters and setters
}

@PostMapping("/")
    public void save(@RequestBody Department department) {
        //can the next line be avoided:
        //department.getEmployees().stream().forEach(e -> e.setDepartment(department));
        departmentRepository.save(department);
    }
```

Sample Request Body:

```
{
    "deptName" : "Sales",
    "employees" : [
        {
            "fullName" : "Test",
            "salary" : 1200.00
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you're using Jackson, have a look at `@JsonBackReference`

Comment: This is because it is a bidirectional relationship. In such cases you need to ensure both sides are set in your in-memory model. The JSON serialization is not going to take care of this for you so you will need to handle it manually as you have in your code or by some other means e.g. by using a @PrePersist entity listener or by writing a custom Jackson  deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the hibernate show_sql property to check what query the hibernate is firing when the save operation is executed. Also you can set the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to create to see the DDL statement.

IMO you are missing the JoinColumn name and nullable attribute it should be like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private Double salary;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="department_id", nullable=false)
    private Department department;
    // getters and setters
}
```